# Unwind without Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

I am replacing my current views in storyboard with xib files. But I encountered an issue about `unwind`.

In Xib files, I can't create unwind segues. And could not find to regular way to this. When I search on web this issue, I just found about "How to perform unwind segue programmatically." This is not what I wanted. I need a way to perform an unwind operation programmatically.

I found [How an Unwind Segue Determines its Destination View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) in Apple Documentation and thought I can do this programmatically. But, the `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:withSender:` method (now it is `forUnwindSegueAction(_:from:withSender:)`) is deprecated and new method for this operation(`childContaining(_:)`) uses an `UIStoryboardUnwindSegueSource` instance that cannot be initialized programmatically.

So, I can see two option.

1. Determine unwind points in app and create operations to do this manually for each of them
2. Create an unwind performer object works like Apple's unwind executor but uses it's own methods.

As I see, the second option is better. But, As I said on beginning of my question. I could not find anything in web, It is like just me encountered this situation and I am sure it is not true. I think I search this with wrong keywords and I need some help to solve this. I want to learn somethings before select one of this options:

- Is there a third way to solve this
- How do you(Programmers that does not use storyboard or xib) solve this problem

Here is some of my Google searches

[Unwind without storyboard](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=unwind%20without%20storyboard)

[Unwind without interface builder](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00vnZxa_q-B60LotEh4Cxwsnelhng%3A1591100818400&ei=kkXWXpX2F9CcmwXstJ5Y&q=unwind%20without%20interface%20builder&oq=unwind%20without%20interface%20builder&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzoECAAQRzoCCAA6BggAEBYQHlCF3QFYrPIBYNqHAmgAcAF4AIABygGIAZIWkgEGMC4xNy4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiVh9S4kOPpAhVQzqYKHWyaBwsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

[How to create unwind segue without storyboard](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00HTRlouXvH69v5rSoL1yL4440m1g%3A1591100852992&ei=tEXWXp-NPITYmwXi1Lg4&q=How%20to%20create%20unwind%20segue%20without%20storyboard&oq=How%20to%20create%20unwind%20segue%20without%20storyboard&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICCEQFhAdEB46BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6AggAOgYIABAWEB46BQgAEMsBOgcIIxDqAhAnOgUIABCRAjoECAAQQzoHCAAQFBCHAjoHCCEQChCgAToECCEQFToFCCEQoAFQgJoEWOzrBGD57ARoAXAGeACAAbIBiAG4NpIBBDAuNDeYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEK&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwift5PJkOPpAhUE7KYKHWIqDgcQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: Hey, I'd suggest  you to take a look at my [UIKitPlus](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus) library. It is much better than xib files, support live preview and works with iOS9+.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion :) I will look at this

Comment: Feel free to find me in Discord as `iMike#3049` I'd love to help with UIKitPlus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone and you are not the first person to have this problem. I call this the problem of *reverse routing*.

To illustrate the problem, I'll show a storyboard version of a relatively complex unwind situation:

[image]

We have a tab bar controller with two children. The first child is a navigation controller which has pushed one view controller (the green v.c. at the end of the first row) on top of its root view controller (the yellow v.c.). The second child is a normal view controller that has presented one view controller (the white v.c. at the end of the second row).

The goal is to unwind from the white v.c. to the *yellow* v.c. in the top row.

If you're using a storyboard, this is trivial. The yellow v.c. contains an `unwind` method (the name isn't actually important), and you "hook" the exit segue from the button in the white v.c. to that method. At runtime, the user taps the button, and the runtime "magically" dismisses the white v.c., switches the tab bar controller to the first child, and pops the green v.c., leaving us in the yellow v.c. as desired.

Now do that in code! Uh, yeah, sure. How? That's the problem.

The irony is palpable. Clearly the runtime *knows* how to solve this problem, because it *does* solve the problem when you use an unwind segue in the storyboard. But there is no built-in programmatic analog when you are *not* using a storyboard. There is no `unwind` command that causes the complex unwind mechanism to become activated and do the same thing that would happen if this were a storyboard-based app.

This is a *huge* flaw in UIKit. Apple basically requires us to use storyboards. But everyone knows that any app developed by a team is likely to avoid storyboards, because reconciling versions of a storyboard through git is darned near impossible. So Apple doesn't seem to live in the real world; they have not provided the runtime support needed for real world development of apps.

A simple solution — simple to the point of crudeness — is just to unwind "by hand". The app has a "coordinator" object whose job is to take care of this sort of backward routing. If you are in the white v.c. and you want to "unwind" to the yellow v.c., your coordinator simply has to *know* that this is something we might want to do, and it *knows* what the necessary steps are in order to get there.

Basically, what I'm saying is that the coordinator must be supplied with a fixed list of all the backward routes the app will ever need to perform, along with instructions for how to perform them. Given where we are and where we want to go back to, the coordinator just performs the corresponding steps.

(You, the OP, will observe that I have not told you anything you don't already know. What I have outlined is, apparently, exactly your option 1. And that is correct. What I'm telling you is: option 2 would be nice, but it doesn't exist and isn't worth trying to write, so just fall back on option 1.)