# How skip ViewController in pressed backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have 3 ViewControllers:

1. StartVC
2. CreateVC
3. MainVC

These ViewControllers pushing sequentially by pressing the button, by `navigationController?.pushViewController`. When the user has all the data in the CreateVC and got into the MainVC, I want that by clicking on the `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`, the user gets not to the CreateVC but to the StartVC.
Tell me a software solution without storyboard pls.

Comment: TL;DR: You cannot. Unless you use a Coordinator. Then I should point you out to study how to implement a Coordinator. This is an already answered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152164/unwind-without-storyboard/62155034#62155034).

Comment: Someone who know how to implement a Coordinator in a simple way of explain, answer this please. I have my Coordinator(S)... but this is not a simple thing to explain. It's a struct to simulate a NavigationStack and to "Coordinate" the order of the ViewControllers stacked on the screen... then you should present the one you want and dealloc the one(S) up on the stack.

Comment: Did you tried popToRootController or popToViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways

(1) If you want to go back to the root (first) ViewController, then use the following function:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

(2) If you want to go back to a specific ViewController in your NavigationStack, use the following function with an extension:

```
// Function:
// `StartVC` must be replaced with the class of the ViewController.

self.navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass: StartVC.self, animated: true)


// Extension:

extension UINavigationController {
  func popToViewController(ofClass: AnyClass, animated: Bool = true) {
    if let vc = viewControllers.last(where: { $0.isKind(of: ofClass) }) {
      popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT: How to add an action to a NavigationButton:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backAction))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

@objc func backAction() {
    // custom actions here
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```